# View rendering decorator for JSON with GAE in Flask

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, flask

I'm trying to write a view rendering decorator for JSON in Flask following this snippet: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/18/

The thing is that I need to serialize as JSON, GAE models, for which the *jsonify* function does not work. For this I'm using the following code: http://blog.worldmaker.net/2009/dec/08/simple-app-engine-json-serialization-snippet/

Similar to the render_html example in the snippet above, I wrote the following code:

```
def render_json(result):
  def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
    json_string = json.dumps(result, cls=GaeEncoder)
    return app.response_class(response=json_string, mimetype='application/json')
  return wrapped
```

The problem is that I invoke a function decorated with my new decorator, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Can anyone point out what is going on here?
Thanks!

Marcos

EDIT: Here is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 208, in Handle
for chunk in result:
File "/Users/mchicote/Documents/projects/schoolnetwork/code/SchoolNetwork/sn/../lib/flaskext/gae_mini_profiler/profiler.py", line 286, in __call__
yield self.prof.runcall(result.next)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/cProfile.py", line 149, in runcall
return func(*args, **kw)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/appstats/recording.py", line 1284, in appstats_wsgi_wrapper
result = app(environ, appstats_start_response)
File "/Users/mchicote/Documents/projects/schoolnetwork/code/SchoolNetwork/sn/../lib/flaskext/gae_mini_profiler/profiler.py", line 269, in wrapped_appstats_app
return old_app(environ, start_response)
File "/Users/mchicote/Documents/projects/schoolnetwork/code/SchoolNetwork/sn/../lib/flask/app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/Users/mchicote/Documents/projects/schoolnetwork/code/SchoolNetwork/sn/../lib/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/Users/mchicote/Documents/projects/schoolnetwork/code/SchoolNetwork/sn/../lib/flask/app.py", line 1361, in full_dispatch_request
response = self.make_response(rv)
File "/Users/mchicote/Documents/projects/schoolnetwork/code/SchoolNetwork/sn/../lib/flask/app.py", line 1450, in make_response
rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
File "/Users/mchicote/Documents/projects/schoolnetwork/code/SchoolNetwork/sn/../lib/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 711, in force_type
response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
File "/Users/mchicote/Documents/projects/schoolnetwork/code/SchoolNetwork/sn/../lib/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 55, in _run_wsgi_app
return _run_wsgi_app(*args)
File "/Users/mchicote/Documents/projects/schoolnetwork/code/SchoolNetwork/sn/../lib/werkzeug/test.py", line 836, in run_wsgi_app
buffer.append(app_iter.next())
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback (including filenames and line numbers)?

Comment: No problem, I'll added to the original post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!
Just in case someone finds it helpful...

The first problem was that I was not following exactly the same pattern described in the snippet above. When I tried following the pattern, I was getting the following error:

```
TypeError: wrapped() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I tried changing the pattern thinking that, as render_json does not take any arguments (in contrast to render_html which takes the template), and wrote the render_json function described above (and the problem described in the original post).
After trying a few things, it occurred to me that I might not have treated the number-of-arguments error correctly, so I went back to writing render_json using the original pattern. I got the following function:

```
def render_json(**defaults):
    def wrapped(result):
        variables = defaults.copy()
        variables.update(result)
        json_string = json.dumps(result, cls=GaeEncoder)
        return app.response_class(response=json_string, mimetype='application/json')                       
    return wrapped
```

Back to the number-of-arguments error, I tried solving it on a different way. Somehow, it occurred to me that the problem might be in the usage of the render_json function. The decorator usage for the render_html looked like this:

```
@view(school_blueprint, '/', render_html('school/index.html'))
```

and the usage of the render_json looked like this:

```
@view(school_blueprint, '/api/list', render_json)
```

Being new at Python, it occurred to me that I was not actually invoking the render_json function but only naming it. Adding () solved the problem. The new usage looks like this:

```
@view(school_blueprint, '/api/list', render_json())
```

Anyway, as I'm new in Python I don't know the technical explanation, but seems to me to be the name vs invoke problem..

Thanks for you help.

Marcos